# Фамилия Булгаков

Tags: этимология

А вот интересно, каково происхождение фамилии Булгаков? По ощущениям, что-то тюркское, но что говорят специалисты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спорный случай. Интерес к фамилии понятен, поэтому, видимо, и мнений много.

*Булгаковы — название нескольких дворянских родов Российской империи.
Распространённая фамилия, вероятно, образована от нецерковного имени тюркского происхождения (прозвища) Булгак — «беспокойный по характеру или вызывающий тревогу ребёнок/человек».

Один из родов Булгаковых — ветвь рода князей Гедиминовичей, через Бельских и Патрикеевых. Ещё один род- это род князя Максима Булгакова,прозванный Белгородским. Два русских дворянских рода Булгаковых — рязанский и московский — оба древнего происхождения. Начало одного известно, а о другом ничего нельзя сказать.*
©Вики.
Добавлю только, что из двух наиболее известных Булкаковых ни писатель Михаил Афанасьевич, ни философ Сергей Николаевич не могли претендовать на принадлежность к этим родам.

Но есть мнение, что фамилия могла иметь не только тюркское происхождение.

Вот из разговора с известным профессором-филологом А.В. Суперанской.

*Фроловская М.П. (Московская область): Уважаемая Александра Васильевна, объясните, пожалуйста, происхождение фамилии моих родителей - Булгаковы. Родом они были из Рязанской области, города Шацка, села Ямская слобода. До брака у обоих была такая фамилия.

Суперанская: Фамилия Булгаков могла возникнуть как в тюркских, так и в русских семьях. Она издавна звучит на Руси во всех слоях общества.

Исторические архивы хранят память о нескольких семьях Булгаковых, перешедших в XV веке на русскую службу из Золотой Орды. Они были хорошо приняты, награждены поместьями, причислены к боярам. Их фамилии образованы от тюркского имени или прозвища Булгак, связанного с глаголом булга "махать (рукой), качать (головой), перемешивать, взбалтывать, мутить, вертеть, пачкать, пакостить". Существительное булгак в отдельных тюркских языках означает: 1. "Смятение". 2. "Гордый человек (вертящий головой)". 3. Праздно шатающийся бездельник"; "непостоянный человек".

Слово булгак вошло во многие русские говоры в значении "беспокойный, суматошный или вздорный человек". Известно также существительное булга "тревога, беспокойство, склока" и глагол булгачить "тревожить, беспокоить, баламутить".

Первые актовые записи, включающие древнерусское имя Булгак, относятся к XV веку:
Булгак, боярин, западные земли, 1466 г.;

Булгак Фролов сын, дьяк в северо-восточных землях, около 1470 г.;

Булгак, холоп в Листовском погосте, 1495 г.

Можно предположить, что в некоторых семьях имя Булгак давалось как предохраняющее, чтобы ребенок не был вздорным или суматошным, а был спокойным, или как защитное: "Придет Лихо за хорошим младенцем, а мы ему скажем, что это булгак: оно и уйдет ни с чем".

Интересен тематический подбор имен детей в семье вяземских бояр Безсоньевых.   Родоначальник семьи звался Безсонье, - а ведь это тоже неспокойное состояние. В середине XVI века дети Василия Яковлевича Безсоньева получили имена: Суета, Суторма (от суторма "суета, беспорядок"), Неустрой и Булгак. Все они были, безусловно, крещеными, но в записи попали только их древнерусские имена, возможно, как более известные.

Семейное прозвание Булгаков фиксируется с начала XVI века: князь Михайло Иванович Булгаков, московский воевода, 1515 г.

Очевидно, возможность и тюркского, и русского происхождения имени Булгак способствовала  популярности фамилии Булгаков.*
©РГ